# Ubuntu 16.04 cross debootstrap - Emulating x86 on ARM64 platform

Tags: crossplatform

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on my ARM64 platform.
I'd like to run x86 code over that platform.
Can I use cross debootstrap to run x86 Ubuntu under chroot (using Qemu for example)?
Is there a tutorial for that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It generally is not a problem to run 32-bit binaries on a 64-bit kernel. A lot of people run multilib systems to get support for both.  (Hence, if you have noticed the lib, lib32 and lib64 directories in the filesystem.) However there are a few options, qemu generally runs an entire virtual machine, often from a hardfile.  Another option is a `container` such as `systemd-nspawn`.

[This link](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apds03.html.en) shows a fairly good example/reference for at least one usage of debootstrap. (Note: `systemd-nspawn` pretty much also uses both debootstrap and a hardfile, but does not require virtualizing a full system).